# Patch a object value into a array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My data in this structure currently

```
{aaa : {
    bbb : 1, ccc : 2
    }
}
```

is it possible patching them in structure below in mongodb shell?

```
{aaa :[ {
    bbb : 1, ccc : 2
    }]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can try [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to make it as an array field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) we can do this

```
db.collection_name.aggregate
([ 
   { $project: 
     { aaa: ["$aaa"] } 
   } 
]);
```

in this approach we have used [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to project the result into the desired format

In case if we want to update the existing collection to this new format, then we have to use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) together with above query. To update the existing collection give the same name of the original collection as parameter for $out.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate
([ 
   { $project: 
     { aaa: ["$aaa"] } 
   },
   {
      $out: "collection_name"
   }  
]);
```